# append /remove anchor name from current url without refresh

Tags: jquery, url, append, anchor

I want that on click event to append/remove the anchor name "#on" to be added to the current url without reloading the page, or use the href='#on' from links because it makes my page jump

Eg: http://www.example.com/page.html#on so I can get the detect the users that come from that url
and call the **On()** function

```
function On()
{   
   //append to current url the anchor "#on"                 
}

function Off()
{   
  //remove from the current url the anchor "#on"                    
}

$('.on').live('click', function() {
  On();
  return false;    
}); 


$('.off').live('click', function() {
  Off();
  return false;    
});
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You don't really need jQuery for that, you can get/set the anchor name using `location.hash`. If you put it in your jQuery ready function, you can do some action if it's set to a certain value:

```
$(function(){
    // Remove the # from the hash, as different browsers may or may not include it
    var hash = location.hash.replace('#','');

    if(hash != ''){
        // Show the hash if it's set
        alert(hash);

        // Clear the hash in the URL
        location.hash = '';
    }
});
```

Note that when removing the hash, the trailing `#` might stay in the address bar. If you want to respond to live changes of the anchor, you can bind a callback to the `hashchange` event:

```
$(document).bind("hashchange", function(){
    // Anchor has changed.
});
```

If you want to prevent your page jumping to the top when clearing the anchor, you can bind the hashchange event to jump back to the previous scroll position. Check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/yVf7V/

```
var lastPos = 0;

$('#on').click(function(){
    location.hash = 'blah';
});

$('#off').click(function(){
    lastPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    location.hash = '';
});

$(window).bind('hashchange',function(event){
    var hash = location.hash.replace('#','');
    if(hash == '') $(window).scrollTop(lastPos);
    alert(hash);
});
```

Comment: thanks dude, it works fine now, except the part where I want to set the location.hash to nothing, as you said it keeps the # at the end of the url and it makes my page jump to top...kinda annoying but I hope to find a workaround. thanks again ;)

Comment: I added a solution to the jumping problem.

Answer (score 20):

if you are using jquery try this code

```
$("a[href^=#]").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.pushState({}, "", this.href);
});
```

Comment: Be aware of browser support for the history API - http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate (basically, IE10+)

Comment: can you write it down as pure JS please?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `history.pushState({}, "", link)` is similar to setting `window.location = "#foo"`, in that both will also create and activate another history entry associated with the current document.

**Note** that `pushState()` never causes a *hashchange* event to be fired, even if the new URL differs from the old URL only in its hash.

```
const url = new URL(window.location);
url.hash = '#foo';
window.history.pushState({}, '', url);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState#examples

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event