# jQuery: how to scroll to certain anchor/div on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lately im trying to use jquery more often and right now im having some problem i'd like to solve with jquery hope u could help me.

I have some web page that includes some anchor tag (lets say the anchor is located in the middle of the page) and on the event onload i want the page to start on that certain anchor tag location meaning the page will be "scrolled" automaticaly to a certain location.

That was my previous solution (which is quite ugly since it adds #i to my url)

```
window.onload = window.location.hash = 'i';
```

Anyway could u tell me how can i do it with jquery?

**notice: i don't want the user to feel any slide or effect while getting to this location**

Comment: so you just want the user to "pop-in" to that section, no slide effects whatsoever?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the following simple example

```
function scrollToElement(ele) {
    $(window).scrollTop(ele.offset().top).scrollLeft(ele.offset().left);
}
```

where `ele` is your element (jQuery) .. for example : `scrollToElement($('#myid'));`

Comment: Works perfect!! :) just for the sport i'd like to learn about more solutions from others though im satisfied right now :)

Comment: @Himu its very simple ... it sets the scroll position of the to the top left of the element you pass in ...

Answer (score 30):

There's no need to use jQuery because this is [native JavaScript functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollIntoView)

```
element.scrollIntoView()
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, the example in the question does not use jQuery

Comment: @ReshapeMedia I agree its the simplest answer - but read the question -> _Anyway could u tell me how can i do it with jquery?_

Comment: scrollIntoView is not a function happened for me.

Comment: based on documentation, its supported in Firefox only

Comment: `scrollIntoView` has wide support (it's the options parameter that's only supported in Firefox)

Comment: This should be executed after page load as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19113062/3917161) said.

Answer (score 18):

I have tried some hours now and the easiest way to stop browsers to jump to the anchor instead of scrolling to it is: Using another anchor (an id you do not use on the site). So instead of linking to "http://#YourActualID" you link to "http://#NoIDonYourSite". Poof, browsers won’t jump anymore.

Then just check if an anchor is set (with the script provided below, that is pulled out of the other thread!). And set your actual id you want to scroll to.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  $(window).load(function(){
    // Remove the # from the hash, as different browsers may or may not include it
    var hash = location.hash.replace('#','');

    if(hash != ''){

       // Clear the hash in the URL
       // location.hash = '';   // delete front "//" if you want to change the address bar
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#YourIDtoScrollTo').offset().top}, 1000);

       }
   });
});
```

See https://lightningsoul.com/media/article/coding/30/YOUTUBE-SOCKREAD-SCRIPT-FOR-MIRC#content for a working example.

Comment: This solution worked like a charm for me, but I've: **a)** decreased animate delay from 1000 to 400; **b)** maintained hash untouched in URL address bar, and **c)** changed `#YourIDtoScrollTo` to `'+hash+'` in order to scroll to whatever dynamic hashes my website offers and user navigates to...

Comment: Sounds good. I would suggest to implement your changes for anyone who needs this. With exception of the delay which is optional to each developers needs. ;)

Comment: Why do you have `$(document).ready(function()` AND `$(window).load(function()`?

Comment: @ChuckLeButt this has been pulled out of another thread as mentioned. I would guess this has been to counter some weird bugs in browsers.
If you want to know more, here's a thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182016/what-is-the-difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready

Answer (score 4):

i achieve it like this..

```
if(location.pathname == '/registration')
{
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#registration').offset().top - 40}, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

Appending the #value into the address is default behaviour that browsers such as IE use to identify named anchor positions on the page, seeing this comes from Netscape.

You can intercept it and remove it, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928435/append-remove-anchor-name-from-current-url-without-refresh) article.

Comment: this is an animated version ... the OP wanted to do it without animation !

Comment: OP could modify code, this is examples of functionality to help him in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
    /* START --- scroll till anchor */
        (function($) {
             $.fn.goTo = function() {
                  var top_menu_height=$('#div_menu_header').height() + 5 ;
                  //alert ( 'top_menu_height is:' + top_menu_height );
                  $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: (-1)*top_menu_height + $(this).offset().top + 'px'
                  }, 500);
                  return this; // for chaining...
             }
        })(jQuery);

        $(document).ready(function(){

          var url = document.URL, idx = url.indexOf("#") ;
          var hash = idx != -1 ? url.substring(idx+1) : "";

          $(window).load(function(){
             // Remove the # from the hash, as different browsers may or may not include it
             var anchor_to_scroll_to = location.hash.replace('#','');
             if ( anchor_to_scroll_to != '' ) {
                 anchor_to_scroll_to = '#' + anchor_to_scroll_to ;
                 $(anchor_to_scroll_to).goTo();
             }
            });
        });
    /* STOP --- scroll till anchror */
```

Answer (score 0):

just use scrollTo plugin

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  $(window).scrollTo("#div")
})
```

Comment: I added the plugin but it still says $("window").scrollTo is not a function

Comment: i am sorry it is $(window).scrollTo("#id") or you can also use $.scrollTo("#id")

Answer (score 0):

Just append `#[id of the div you want to scroll to]` to your page url. For example, if I wanted to scroll to the copyright section of this stackoverflow question, the URL would change from

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757625/jquery-how-to-scroll-to-certain-anchor-div-on-page-load
```

to

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757625/jquery-how-to-scroll-to-certain-anchor-div-on-page-load#copyright
```

notice the `#copyright` at the end of the URL.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)