# How do i load page with default hash (ID) content?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page, named as `index.html` and i want to load it as `index.html#home`

Because i do have few elements with different ID's, and i want to load the #home content by default.

So when we hit `index.html` page it will reload to `index.html#home` (unless if no hash is specified in the URL)

How its possible? and forgive my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this (Check  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.location))

```
if(!window.location.hash) {
    location.hash = '#home';
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/vXSbe/3/)

Comment: it will go to index.hrml#home content even if i tried to go for index.html#contact. any solution by adding if condition?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get it what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the (NOT `head` - see comments) **bottom** of your html page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     document.getElementById("home").scrollIntoView();
</script>
```

Comment: Surely you'd have to wait for the DOM to be ready before that would work?

Comment: Yes, I am sure you are right!  This should work when placed at the bottom of the HTML page, not top.

Comment: This should be executed after page load as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19113062/3917161) said.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is scroll to a div on pageload, I suggest reading (/applying) this:

[jQuery: how to scroll to certain anchor/div on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757625/jquery-how-to-scroll-to-certain-anchor-div-on-page-load)