# ScrollIntoView in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I use:

```
var el = document.getElementById("centd");
el.scrollIntoView(true);
```

to scroll to specific position. In every browser it works fine, but in Chrome when the page is loaded it scrolls to that point, but after a second or two (when the page is finished loading) it scrolls back to start.

Comment: You can use this plugin: http://erraticdev.blogspot.com.ar/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445842/does-scrollintoview-work-in-all-browsers?lq=1

Comment: Are you doing that eg. in DOMContentLoaded event, not directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure all your JavaScript code is run after your page completes loading:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   // your code here
}, false);
```

Or if you're using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// your code
});
```

This will make sure that your code runs the way you intend.

Comment: Strange - when I call document.getElementById from <body onload="..." there is no error, but when calling it through 'DOMContentLoaded' it's NULL.

Comment: my bad - just made a reproducer to test on chrome and Firefox, but it works on both, I must have made a mistake in my implementation when attempting this.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like it's supposed to be a feature and not a bug (but cannot find evidence to support this theory): it works fine the first time the page loads / in a new tab, but as soon as the user scrolled, that scroll-position overrides any `scrollTo` or `scrollIntoView` commands (in this briefly flashing fashion you described, and that I am currently trying to make sense of) – even if you wait for the document to be ready.

Other browsers don't share this behavior, in my experience.