# Scrolling to a specific div using window.onload without adding to the web address

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, navigation, onload-event

I am creating a page with 5 divs. I am using the following JavaScript code to smoothly move between them horizontaly :

```
    $(function () {
    $('ul.nav a').bind('click', function (event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
        }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The Divs are something like this:

```
 <div class="section white" id="section5">
            <h2>Technologies</h2>
            <p>
                text

            </p>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#section1">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section2">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section3">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section4">4</a></li>
                <li>5</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**I want to start with div # 3 on page load.** The only solution that worked is the onload function:

```
window.onload = window.location.hash = 'section3';
```

but unfortunately when I load the page the url address is

```
http://localhost:51551/trial1/MainPage.aspx#section3
```

even when I click on another page anchors (div) and go there the URL is stuck to MainPage.aspx#section3.

I tried the solutions here: [jQuery: how to scroll to certain anchor/div on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757625/jquery-how-to-scroll-to-certain-anchor-div-on-page-load)

But I think because I am already using Javascript to navigate the divs, its not working. I want to Either:

1. Remove the address #section3 part and keep using the onload
   function
2. Even better navigate to section3 at start and have
       the url change when I change the section

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express, with ASP.NET, JS and C#. on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the following important distinction:

- jQuery's `#section1` selector looks for an **HTML element with ID "section1"**, i.e. `<div id="section1"></div>`
- The a href's `#section1` URL hash looks for an **anchor with name "section1"**, i.e. `<a name="section1"></a>`

This is a major difference that you need to check and understand. So you would normally need:

```
<a name="section1"></a>
<div id="section1">... your content here ...</div>
```

But since you are scrolling horizontally, I am going to do this without the `<a name=...></a>` part and deal with the hash in the window load handler, as I will explain further down.

Next is, I would avoid naming a JavaScript variable "event" as that looks an awful lot like a keyword, so try renaming it to `ev`.

If you want the click handler (the function you bind to the `click` event) to not follow the link clicked on, that function should return false:

```
$('ul.nav a').click(function (ev) {
    var anchor = $(this);
    $('.viewport').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: $($(anchor).attr('href')).offset().left
    }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');

    // Add the section ID to the URL
    window.location.hash = $(anchor).attr('href').substring(1);

    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Then, I'd suggest you to move the `<ul class="nav">...</ul>` outside of the section divs, so you don't have to repeat it inside your divs. Because you seem to be scrolling left/right, I assume you are floating your section divs next to each other in a wide container:

```
<div class="viewport">
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="section" id="section1">
            <h2>Technologies</h2>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="section" id="section2">
            ... content ...
        </div>
        <div class="section" id="section3">
            ... content ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#section1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Using the following CSS (as an example for 3 600px divs floated next to each other inside a 1800px container, wrapped by a 600px viewport):

```
.viewport {
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.container {
  width: 1800px;
}
.section {
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
}
```

For the `clearfix` class, refer to [Bootstrap's clearfix](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-clearfix).

Because you are scrolling horizontally, I think the `<a name=...></a>` things won't work, so I'd do an onload check for the hash, and scroll there when accessing the page with a preset hash. This has been done in the window load handler in the next snippet, together with starting in section 3 when there is no hash specified:

As for starting in section 3 on load, have this in your `$(window).load()` handler, for example:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   var startSection = window.location.hash;
   if (startSection == "") startSection = '#section3';

   $('.viewport').scrollLeft($(startSection).offset().left);
   window.location.hash = startSection;
});
```

**Disclaimer: untested code!** :) But please try these, and it should get you pretty close to what you are trying to achieve.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, unfortunately it didn't change.

Comment: @user1821444 Did you see my comment about anchor names vs div ids? JQuery sees "#section3" as an element with ID section3, while href="#section3" looks for an anchor with name "section3".

Comment: Thank you !!. your new comment didn't get loaded at first -- I used your "go to section by default" solution and it worked. so now I start at 3 with no addition to the url address --- However I didn't add the return false; part as I actually don't know what is the handler function :) --- Also I added the <a name=""> you suggested and it didn't change any thing --- But anyway It worked now !!! Thank you. If you can advise how can I now represent the section name in the URL when I navigate, that would be great

Comment: I have updated the answer. Hope it covers all your questions!

Comment: The new solution didn't work :( when I removed the navigator outside the div it just stayed at the first page and didn't appear on all pages

Comment: What do you mean: // Add the section ID to the URL ??

Comment: I managed to rearrange it so now the navigation is outside and its working but no Javascript transition is working, Do I need to add something to the javascript you mentiond above, Note: I changed the section IDs to (Home, Contact Us, About Us, ....) does this matter in the Javascript function

Comment: Ah, I think I made a mistake. It is the viewport that should be scrolling. In that case it is the ".viewport" that should receive the scroll, and not html/body. I have updated the JavaScript code in the answer.
The "//" starts a one-line comment, so it is just a comment telling you what the next line does.
The section IDs should not contain spaces. And yes, it matters. If in JavaScript, you refer to something $('#name'), it looks for an element with exactly id="name" as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you scroll to that div on window load? And change bind with on, as of jQuery 1.7 .on() is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document

So your code should be something like this

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('ul.nav a ').on('click ', function (event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body ').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo ');

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});


$(window).on('load', function () {

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: $('#section3').offset().left
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo ');

});
```

Comment: This solution didn't work, the animation that was working before didn't work, and it didn't start at section 3 ---

Note that I have no jQuery experience