# How do I load site at a specific div

Tags: jquery, load

I have started to build a website, based on the structure from this codpen:

http://bit.ly/1DIHGSy

My problem is, that I want the page to load on to the last slide?

A have tried to make an anchor point, and make the page load to the anchor point, whiteout any luck. I have also tried to make a script based on this post:

[jQuery: how to scroll to certain anchor/div on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757625/jquery-how-to-scroll-to-certain-anchor-div-on-page-load)

Again whiteout any luck. Do anyone have an idea on how to solve this issue?

**notice: I don't want the user to feel any slide or effect while getting to this location**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you call `goToSlide($currentSlide);` in line 27 that is the first slide, instead do:

```
goToSlide($('#slide-7'));
```

but then you'll have the sliding animation so you can upgrade the function to accept duration argument:

```
function goToSlide($slide, duration)
{

    if(typeof(duration) === 'undefined'){
       duration = 1;
    }

    //...

        TweenLite.to($slidesContainer, duration, {scrollTo: {y: pageHeight * $currentSlide.index() }, onComplete: onSlideChangeEnd, onCompleteScope: this});

    // ...
}
```

and then in line 27:

```
goToSlide($('#slide-7'), 0)
```

or better yet when you defining variable:

```
var $currentSlide = $slides.first();
```

make it last slide in the first place:

```
var $currentSlide = $slides.last();
```

Comment: so the goToSlide($('#slide-7')); does work. Thanks

But when I try to upgrade the function to accept duration argument, the slide function doesn't seem to work at all. 

Is there another way to bypass this problem ?