# how to show smooth parallax scrolling effect in mobile devices

Tags: jquery

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var target = this.hash;
                    $target = $(target);
                    $target.addClass('active');
                    $('html, body').stop().animate({
                        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
                        }, 1000, 'swing');
});
```

HTML Code

```
                        <div style="position: fixed;font-size:15px">

                                <a href="#header-wrapper">Home</a><br>
                                <a href="#about">About</a>  <br>
                                <a href="#programme">The System</a><br>


                            </div>

<div class="title" id="header-wrapper">Content</div>
<div class="title" id="about">Content</div>

<div class="title" id="programme">Content</div>
```

I have used this script code to show parallax effect. It works perfectly in web but not in mobile devices. How to make it work in mobile devices. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Use `tap` event how this:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on("tap",function(){
  // Your code
});
```

Comment: tap isn't working..using tap event removes the smooth scroll even in web.

Comment: Please, can you indicate what OS and browser are you using?

Comment: browser is Chrome and OS is android

Comment: And what's exactly doesn't work? Click, animation...?

Comment: In this case, I have not differences between Web Desktop and Mobile. Maybe it's a problem with your browser mobile

Comment: Can u please tell how to remove anchor from the end of url when it is in a particular section.Like removing #about from end of url. Thank you

Comment: Solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928435/append-remove-anchor-name-from-current-url-without-refresh)