# disable url change when link to a different part of the same page is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

suppose I have a button on `www.domain.com` linking to a lower part of the page through an anchor tag `<a href="#destination">text link</a>`

is it possible to prevent the url in url bar of the browser from showing `www.domain.com/#destination`?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [append /remove anchor name from current url without refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928435/append-remove-anchor-name-from-current-url-without-refresh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```js
$("a.anchor").on("click", function(e) {      
    e.preventDefault();
    $(window).scrollTop($($(this).attr('href')).offset().top);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<a href="#second" class="anchor">Second</a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h2 id="second">Second Part</h2>
```

Now the anchor link shows the address on hover, But scrolls to destination instead of navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery like this:

```
$("#down").click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#b").offset().top
    });
});

$("#up").click(function ()
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#a").offset().top
    });
})
```

Hope this helps.

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZGk5F/